# Integration against Eisenstein series can be regarded as a cup product

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, iwasawa-theory

This summer, I was very fortunate and honored to attend the conference "Iwasawa 2023" at the University of Cambridge as a young Ph.D. student on Iwasawa theory. There, one of the speakers, might be Professor David Loeffler, mentioned that on the automorphic side, **"integration against Eisenstein series can be regarded as a cup product in the coherent cohomology"**.

I am very interested in such (might be geometric?) interpretation of the integrations against Eisenstein series, so I wonder where I can find the precise meaning of the above "slogan"? More specifically, I would like to know the references explaining

- What is the "coherent cohomology", what does it mean and how can it be used?
- How to regard the integration against Eisenstein series as a cup product in the coherent cohomology?

Of course, it would be of great help if one could explain these in the answer of this post. I am so sorry if this post is not appropriate for this site, and thank you so much for paying attention, commenting, or answering. :)

Comment: Loeffler's reference is https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.16114 , section 5.1

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you so much! That helps a lot!

Comment: For what it's worth, the particular paper I was referring to was a different one, https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.07004. But the one from Carlo's link does indeed use the same methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that does indeed sound like something I might have said :)

I was referring to some extremely powerful theorems, originally due to Michael Harris, which show that:

- The cohomology groups of automorphic vector bundles on toroidal compactifications of Shimura varieties are isomorphic to certain spaces of (usually non-holomorphic) automorphic forms. (These vector bundles are coherent sheaves, hence "coherent cohomology".)
- Via this isomorphism, the Serre duality pairing on coherent cohomology groups is given by integration of automorphic forms.

The general results are all set out in Harris' paper "[Automorphic forms of $\overline{\partial}$-cohomology type as coherent cohomology classes](https://doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214445036)" (J. Diff. Geom. 1990); the relation between Serre duality and integrals is Proposition 3.8.

To get some feel for how this is applied in practice I recommend reading some other papers of Harris from around the same time, e.g. this one with Kudla: [Arithmetic automorphic forms for the nonholomorphic discrete series of GSp(2)](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-92-06603-8).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And for your wonderful inspiring talk at Cambridge! :)